The twin prime problem and the Jurkat-Richert Theorem
Where does the Jurkat-Richert Theorem for linear sieves fail when applied to the twin prime problem?
I'm reading the last two chapters of Additive Number Theory The Classical Bases. The  Jurkat-Richert Theorem [Theorem 9.7] was applied to prove Chern's theorem. One step in the proof is to obtain a lower bound for the function $S(A,\mathcal{P}, z)$ [Theorem 10.4]. This theorem gives that $$S(A,\mathcal{P},z)> \left(\frac{e^{\gamma}\log 3}{2} +O(\epsilon)\right)\frac{NV(z)}{\log N}.$$ But if we replace the set $A$ by $A=\{p+2| p\text{ is a prime}, 2<p\leq N\}$ and let the set of prime $\mathcal{P} $ to be  $\mathcal{P}=\{ p| p\text{ is a prime}, p\neq 2\}$, then it looks like a similar estimate works to give $S(A,\mathcal{P},z)> \left(\frac{e^{\gamma}\log 3}{2} +O(\epsilon)\right)\frac{NV(z)}{\log N}$ which would be positive.
There must be something not working here but I can't see where the problem is.

I don't think there is something wrong here at all: note that $z=N^{1/8}$ in Chapter 10, so lower bounding $S(A,\mathcal{P},z)$ does not prove existence of twin primes. To put this in context, recall Chen has two theorems: one theorem, proved in Chapter 10 of the book you link to, says that large even $n$ is a sum of a prime and a number which is either a prime or a product of two primes. But Chen also proved that there are infinitely many primes $p$ such that $p+2$ is either a prime or a product of two primes - and the proof is similar (you are basically arriving at it).

(Stanley's answer below explains why you cannot expect to solve the twin prime conjecture using the Jurkat-Richert theorem alone.)

Also, it is not CHERN'S theorem, but CHEN'S theorem. Their surnames are the same in Chinese (陈) but Chern refers to Shiing-Shen Chern （陈省身）whereas the Chen in Chen's theorem refers to Jingrun (J.R.) Chen (陈景润）

This is a fundamental problem in the theory of sieves. It was Selberg who identified the problem in a sense, in that the basic mechanism of sieves can never beat the so-called parity barrier. In essence (see the following Wikipedia page for a quick exposition), the set of positive integers with an even number of prime factors behaves almost identically to combinatorial sieves that are the foundation of results like the Jurkat-Richert theorem to the set of numbers with an odd number of prime factors. Of course, the former set contains no primes by its very definition. Thus, the combinatorial sieve can never detect primes on their own, without additional input. A lot of sieves, including the linear sieve and Selberg's sieve, are more sophisticated variants of the combinatorial sieve.
In order to beat the parity barrier, the standard extra input is some sort of bilinear sum estimate or some sort of Type II information. The latter terminology comes from Vaughan's identity, where a sum weighted by the von Mangoldt function is broken down into subsums of "Type I" and "Type II".
Friedlander and Iwaniec showed in 1998 how Type II information can be used to produce prime-detecting sieves: see their article Asymptotic sieve for primes.
Very recently, Ford and Maynard have taken a very important step beyond Friedlander and Iwaniec, the first comprehensive advance in understanding the foundation and molecular structure of sieves in many decades. Among other things, they showed that there are examples where a small, non-zero amount of Type II information still does not suffice to produce primes; there must be enough Type I and Type II information in order to guarantee the existence of infinitely many primes in a sequence. Their article is here: On the theory of prime producing sieves.

As discussed in Stanley's answer, the main overarching reason why we cannot prove the Twin Prime conjecture (or Goldbach's conjecture) is the parity problem. However, in terms of the specific lower bound you have provided there is another restriction.
In particular, Nathanson has $z=N^{1/8}$ so that $S(A,P(z))>0$ implies every sufficiently large even integer can be written as the sum of a prime, and a number with at most 8-1=7 prime factors. To get Chen's theorem one then needs to also use the upper sieve bounds proven in Section 10.5 and 10.6 of Nathanson's textbook.
If one wished to increase the value of $z$ then you are restricted by the condition $D\geq z^2$ appearing in the Jurkat-Richert theorem (Theorem 9.7 in Nathanson). Since here $D=N^{1/2-\epsilon}$ one can at best take $z=N^{1/4-\epsilon}$. This would give that every sufficiently large even integer can be written as the sum of a prime and a number with at most $4$ prime factors. Or, in terms of the twin prime problem: there are infinitely many primes $p$ such that $p+2$ has at most 4 prime factors.
